# c# #region/#endregion mismatch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, region

Anyone know a good way to find out where i have an extra #region or #endregion in my code? I have about 5000 lines of c# code and i'm trying to do it manually right now. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @toosweetnightmare Tejs is correct; the fact that you have a mismatched region is a sign of a larger problem. After you find your issue, I recommend doing what you can to keep each class as small as possible.

Comment: Partial classes are great for this, or separate classes ;-)

Comment: I have it broken into classes and i like to break the code in the classes up into little regions with titles to manage it. It might not be best practice but i'm not a software engineer and it works for me.

Comment: It sounds kind of like it's not working actually.  I think the idea is that your class is too big.

Comment: I think ill just take Tejs advice and remove all of my #region and #endregion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> -  to close up all the regions.  Then expand them one at a time on the left (little `+` sign) until you see `#region XXX` that doesnt have matching `#endregion`

Should look like this:

[image: Mismatch]

Comment: Thanks SwDevMan81. i did this already. I might just do a replace on all my #regions with a // and replace my #endregion with // too just to remove the issue.

Comment: thanks for the update. Im going to try that now. Ill be back in a few minutes and let you know how it went.

Comment: That worked. Ended up being a stupid typo actually. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Click `Ctrl+M, M` it will collapse all properly matching regions. The one that doesn't match will not be collapsed so you can fix it.

Comment: Doing this closed everything except for a lone #endregion i had to put at the end to remove the error

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you use the shortcuts to collapse all?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Collapse all regions not recursively

It should collapse all but the region that has the mismatch.

Comment: it leaves my namespace open and my class open

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue myself,

easiest way for me to find out where I had deleted an endregion was to do a compare with the last file in source control.

the line was then highlighted and easy to find.

Comment: an excellent suggestion. I unfortunately did not have a previous copy to use for source control but i can see how this would have been a very useful. Thank you for adding to my question!